# How to change my tabs are making the content below indent?

Tags: css, tabs, indentation

My HTML for the tabs is:

```
<ul id = "tabs">
    <li id = "home" onclick = "document.location.href = \'/\'">Home</a></li>
    <li id = "games" onclick = "document.location.href = \'/games/\'">Games</li>
    <li id = "tutorials" onclick = "document.location.href = \'/tutorials/\'">Tutorials</li>
    <li id = "snippets" onclick = "document.location.href = \'/snippets/\'">Snippets</li>
    <li id = "people" onclick = "document.location.href = \'/people.php\'">People</li>
    </ul>
```

And the CSS for them is:

```
#tabs {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 #tabs li { 
     display:inline; 
     float:left;
     position:relative;
     left:0px;
     top:-30px;
     padding: 9px;
     padding-top: 2px;
     padding-bottom: 2px;
     margin-left: 5px;
     border-top: 2px solid #03c;
     border-left: 2px solid #03c;
     border-right: 2px solid #03c;
     border-top-right-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
     border-top-left-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
     background-color: #dddddd;
     height: 24px;
     font-family: trebuchet ms;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
```

And for some reason, on my pages, the tabs take up space in the things underneath. See what I mean [here](http://www.scribblingmaniac.co.uk/tutorials/).
And yes, I know some links go to nowhere. It's still being set up.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking here - can you clarify your problem a bit?

Comment: I have an unordered list that I'm using a tab navigation thing for my website. It however forces the content and heading below to indent to in front of the tabs - I don't want it to indent at all. Look at what I mean in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<li>` elements in your `#tabs` list has a position of `top: -30px`. However, `#tabs` is being displayed in line with the `.content`. This seems to fix your problem:

```
#tabs {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     margin-bottom: -35px;
     display: inline-block;
 }
```